# The probability that something happens less frequent than a given value given the mean

Tags: probability

How would I approach this question? The average duration of Alzheimer’s disease is 8 years and the standard deviation is 4 years. For a clinical study 30 patients, who have been determined to be at the very beginning stage of the disease, are randomly selected. What is the probability that the average duration of the disease among the sampled
patients will be less than 7 years?

I just don't know where to start, or what to search for to start to understand how to approach this kind of problem
There must be a formula, but what is it called so I can look into it?

Comment: I've been trying to use probability Distributions, but sure that's not it. I just dont know where to research to work it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Note that

$$\frac{\bar{X}-\mu}{\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}}\sim N(0,1)$$

where $N(0,1)$ means that it follows a standard normal distribution.

A $z$-table gives the cumulative density of standard normal random variables. We have that

$$\mathbb{P}\left(Z\lt \frac{\bar{X}-\mu}{\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}}\right)=\Phi\left(\frac{\bar{X}-\mu}{\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}}\right)$$

where $$\Phi(z)=\mathbb{P}(Z\lt z)$$ when $$Z\sim N(0,1)$$

Can you go from here?

Comment: Yes, this has given me enough to go off!! Thanks! :)